# recursive data manipulation

Tags: javascript

Suppose we are receiving this object array:

```
[
    {
        ownerId: 1,
        personName: John,
        petsOwned: [
            {
                petId: 1,
                petName: Fluffy,
                petType: cat,
                diseases: [
                    {
                        diseaseId: 1,
                        diseaseName: A,
                    },
                    {
                        diseaseId: 2,
                        diseaseName: B,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                petId: 2,
                petName: Biscuit,
                petType: dog,
                diseases: [
                    {
                        diseaseId: 3,
                        diseaseName: G,
                    },
                    {
                        diseaseId: 4,
                        diseaseName: Z,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                petId: 3,
                petName: Ant,
                petType: hamster,
                diseases: [
                    {
                        diseaseId: 5,
                        diseaseName: Vx,
                    },
                    {
                        diseaseId: 6,
                        diseaseName: T1,
                    },
                    {
                        diseaseId: 55,
                        diseaseName: YU,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

which cascades like this 4 or even more times and every cascade doesn't have any information about its parent object.

I mean taking out `Fluffy` from would end up having no owner because it doesnt have an `ownerId` in it.

If there would be more than 50 of those owners having random number of pets and those pets may have random number of diseases or anything you like, how would you return a complete list of pets diseases, is there a way todo it without using loops within loops within loops and so on in JavaScript?

Thank you for your time and I hope it is clear enough to understand what I am asking.

Comment: Your data doesn't seem to be arbitrarily recursive, it has a clear hierarchy: owners->pets->diseases, each with distinct property names. Using nested loops is totally fine for this.

Comment: Is expected result `ownerId` _and_ `diseases` , or, only all `diseases` ?

Comment: It's always going to be some sort of loop if this is how your data is stored. This behavior is not specific to JSON either--the same could be said of XML or even SQL databases. Unless you store the data differently, you are going to have to query all records to get your result.

Comment: As @dave said you'll need to store the data in intermediate form (dbms or maps in memory) for you to efficiently query this data.  Or parse it and create indexes suited for your queries.

Comment: So I suspect that if I would decide to make a big array of pets throughtout the owners I would not be able to find which pet belongs to whom unless I add ownerId to every pet? I mean there is no other way to achieve this without losing data about parent object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. you still have to go through the object, and thus have to use loops, then the easiest way of doing this is first converting this to a javascript object using JSON.parse.

So you can do something like

```
var john = JSON.parse(string);
```

Then you can start by writing a simple function that gets every disease from a certain pet and returns it in an array such as

```
var getDiseaseId = function() {
     var ret = new Array();
     for(var i = 0; i < diseases.length; i++)
         ret.push(diseases[i].diseaseId);
     return ret;
 }
```

When you've done that, you can start building going through all of the pets, getting every disease they have and then return one final array

```
var allDiseases = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < john.petsOwned.length; i++) {
      allDiseases.push.apply(allDiseases, getDiseaseId(john.petsOwned[i]));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is mostly okay, with the exception that you have the potential for redundancy inside of "diseases" definitions. What would it mean if one pet has the same disease ID as another, but a different disease name? If you were to define your JSON as an object instead of an array, you could include both a field for "owners", which contains "pets"; as well as a small database of all diseases which are contained in this dataset. Then, instead of having disease structures inside pets, the diseases array would just have diseaseIds.

This would be especially useful if diseases start getting more complex, and several pets in a result start including the same one twice. As well as saving on transfer size, it would also reduce the number of "moving parts" so to speak.

There are other situations where I'd suggest storing Owners, Pets, and Diseases all separately, but each one of those types requires an owner to have any logical meaning, so otherwise I feel it's fine as is; the thing that sets diseases apart is that several pets can have the same disease, but several owners can't have the same pet.

Answer (score 0):

Build a recursive function--this way you can change the way the data is structured and still use the same function to build your array.

```
var doRecursion = function(items, targetKey, type) {
    type = type || "";
    var results = [];

    if (type == targetKey) {

        return items;

    } else if (typeof items == "object" && items != null) {

        for (var i in items) {
            var moreItems = doRecursion(items[i], targetKey, i);
            for (j in moreItems) {
                results.push(moreItems[j]);
            }
        }

    } 

    return results;
}

console.log(doRecursion(pets, "diseases"));
```

See fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bq2cz27m/).